# Keras LSTM batched time-series input giving constant accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have a time-series data set with 1 feature that represents multiple games. The goal is to classify each game as a win or loss - binary classification. Each game has 61 rows, and the feature has been scaled to be between 0 and 1:

```py
x_train = array([[0.55340617],
                 [0.54956823],
                 [0.54588505],
                 ...,
                 [0.87483364],
                 [0.8956947 ],
                 [0.90343248]])
y_train = array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])
```

The problem should be quite easy, and I was expecting around 70% accuracy based on other models.

I'm trying to train an LSTM with the data. I think I should be resetting the state on every game, and so the batch shape is defined by 61 timesteps, and 1 feature:

```py
timesteps = 61
n_features = 1

# Reshape data for LSTM
x_train = x_train.reshape(len(x_train)//timesteps, timesteps, n_features)

# Get class of each game
y_train = x_test[0: len(y_train): timesteps]

model = Sequential()

# Hidden layer
n_neurons = 8
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons,
               input_shape=(timesteps, n_features),
               stateful=False))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          epochs=3,
          batch_size=1)
```

But when I train the model, the accuracy remains constant:

```
Epoch 1/3
301/301 [==============================] - 7s 23ms/step - loss: 8.2524 - accuracy: 0.4618
Epoch 2/3
301/301 [==============================] - 6s 21ms/step - loss: 8.2524 - accuracy: 0.4618
Epoch 3/3
301/301 [==============================] - 6s 21ms/step - loss: 8.2524 - accuracy: 0.4618
```

I have tried switching the optimiser to 'RMSprop', but I get the exact same result? I think the problem lies with the batch shape?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Fixed some typos in the code. Sorry!

Comment: have you tried sigmoid instead of softmax

Comment: No I did not! The accuracy has shot up: 0.6179 -> 0.8140 -> 0.8505! Massive thank you, I've been stuck on this all day, I was looking in the wrong place all along!